# Pageviews by Source/Medium in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

I know that generally we shouldn't combine metrics and dimensions of different scope, however I also know that there are some exceptions.

Is Pageviews by Source/Medium one of those exceptions? And if yes, why are we allowed to combine them?

Comment: I'm must not understand the question because I use that combination all of the time.

Comment: Are you asking because "Source/Medium" is session scope, but pageviews are page scope?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes exactly.